# What is the usefulness of a component declaration?

Tags: vhdl

With VHDL '93 introducing direct instantiation, when would you actually use a component now when your entity is in VHDL? The following are the only time when a component is required I can think of:

1. Component maps to non VHDL source (Verilog, netlist etc)
2. You don't have the source yet and need something to compile against (eg. colleague hasn't finished their code yet)
3. You are binding different entity/architecture pairs to specific components in specific entities via configs. (but who ever actually does this? maybe if you have a simulation arch and synth arch - but again - never seen it used in any meaningful way)

I am discounting people who say that "A component lets me see the port map in the same file" or "having a component library allows me to see everything". This is mostly an old-school approach that people have got into the habit of. In my eyes, maintaining the same code in two places makes no sense.

Are there any others I've missed?

Comment: Your parenthesized comments and last paragraph solicit opinions on usage. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.8 Component declarations "A component declaration declares an interface to a virtual design entity that may be used in a component instantiation statement. A component configuration or a configuration specification can be used to associate a component instance with a design entity that resides in a library."

Comment: But I am after an example where the component declaration is required rather than where is may optionally be used. Having a component declaration inside a file or inside a package for those instances I mentioned is usually nothing more than a coding style, rather than a code requirement (leaving aside companies who's coding guidelines require it).

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. I can't think of any other reasons but 2 and 3 (and haven't come across a simulator that requires 1, but I've not done a survey).

Comment: ***What is the usefulness of a component declaration?*** 11.7.2 Instantiation of a component "A component instantiation statement whose instantiated unit contains a name denoting a component is equivalent to a pair of nested block statements that couple the block hierarchy in the containing design unit to a unique copy of the block hierarchy contained in another design unit ... The outer block represents the component declaration; the inner block represents the design entity to which the component is bound. Each is defined by a block statement." The component declaration is required here.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor please see my answer for other use cases.

Comment: Thank you @Paebbels. Your 1 is interesting. I think I would agree that it's a bug. I've done 2 myself (with a home grown verification environment based on Janick Bergeron's "Writing Testbenches". In fact, that's the only time I have ever used a configuration in real projects. (I have done more Verilog than VHDL.)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the late response to [Can't compile VHDL package - Modelsim error: (vcom-1576) expecting END](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761177/cant-compile-vhdl-package-modelsim-error-vcom-1576-expecting-end/52761664#comment92461972_52761664)

In addition to the use case listed by the OP and in compliance with his criteria of not so useful cases, I'll add two more cases:

1. To write platform independent code, one needs to implement e.g. an Altera and a Xilinx specific solution. This code will reference vendor specific libraries like `alter_mf` or `unisim`. Both vendor specific implementations can be selected by a *if ... generate*-statement, or since VHDL-2008 by a *case ... generate*-statement.
   But even with *generate*-statements, this solution needs to instantiate components, because instances of a direct entity instantiation are bound regardless of the fact that some instances will never appear in the elaborated model. (I consider this a bug in the language - but there was no time to investigate and fix it for VHDL-2018.) Because an entity is immediately bound, the tool tries to load the referenced vendor library and it's packages.
   Let's assume you compile on Altera with Quartus, it will complain about an unknown `unisim` library and a unknown `vcomponents` package. The same happens on Xilinx with Vivado complaining about an unknown `altera_mf` library.
   Thus, to cut-off the (direct) instantiation tree, a component instantiation is needed.

   This technique is used by the [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC). See for example the [`PoC.misc.sync.Bits`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/misc/sync/sync_Bits.vhdl?ts=2) implementation for a standard double-FF synchronizer with different attributes applied to an Altera, Xilinx or generic implementation.
2. In the [Open Source VHDL Verification Methodology (OSVVM)](https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM), components are used for two use cases:

   1. In a toplevel DUT, IP cores are instantiated as components so they can be replaced by dummy implementations. Either as unbound components or as components loading a dummy architecture. This can speed up simulations, reduce possible error sources in testing, replace complex slow implementations like MGTs or memory controllers with simpler and faster implementations, ...
   2. In OSVVM, the test control is implemented in a separate entity called `TestController`. This entity has several architectures to implement the different test cases applied to the same test hardness. The architectures are bound with a toplevel configuration per test case / architecture. Thus, running a "testbench" means elaborating and simulating one of these configurations.